# Why ping is not a client-server type thing?

Tags: ping

I've read somewhere that ping requests-responses don't work like a client-server. How?
We(sender) send a packet of data(ping) and if the server is up, it'll send back a packet. Isn't this a client-server type communication?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We(sender) send a packet of data(ping) and if the server is up, it'll send back a packet

This is not the definition of client/server, it just means you have bidirectional traffic, which you also have in p2p applications.

One could argue that strictly speaking the "ping" utility (application?) that you execute,  can be considered to be a *client* because it always sends echo requests and then processes the responses it gets. And so the part of the IP stack in the remote device that sends back the echo could be considered a *server*.

Another way of looking at it is that every device on an IP network can send echo requests *and* respond to them, so from this perspective there are no clients vs servers but all are equal peers, and hence "pinging" (what I assume you mean with the "ping application") is more of a kind of peer-to-peer functionality.  Which I *guess* it what laika and Datagrem.Network are hinting at in their answers, but not explicitly saying.

In the end IMHO it's more of a semantic than a really technical discussion, and I would even argue that ping is not even an "application" to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Ping uses ICMP echo messages.

Quoting from [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792), the specification on ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol):

> ICMP is actually an integral part of IP, and must be implemented by every IP module.

There's no need to start any service to be started and listen on particular port for ICMP messages.

Comment: So the server is the kernel's network stack, is it not?

Comment: Then when do we call an application a client-server one? Is it involvement of the 4th layer?

Comment: The term client or server does not have clear technological meaning without the context. In the context of ICMP there's no distinction in the role of any involved host. However you cannot generalize that the differentiation between server or client start at 4th layer and higher  - take as an example RARP, where one f the hosts is required to have special position amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the ubiquitous network request/response concept with the application client/server response.

In the network layers (OSI layers 1 to 4), everything is a peer-to-peer connection. Peers can query each other, and receive responses from each other. This is not a client/server concept. Each peer at layer-3 could ping the other peer and receive a response. It is a two-way street, and that is peer-to-peer.

The client/server concept is an application concept. For instance, a web browser can request a web page from a web server, and it gets a web page in response, but a web server cannot request a web page from a web browser. It is a one way street, and that is client/server.

Answer (score 0):

ICMP is implemented directly on top of IP packets and doesn't use a transport layer (OSI layer 4) like TCP or UDP and is integral part of IP.
RFC 792 defines ICMP, which provides routing, diagnostic and error functionality for IP. Although ICMP messages are encapsulated within IP datagrams, ICMP processing is considered to be (and is typically implemented as) part of the IP layer.